# Doxygen comments for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, doxygen

I have a third party package which has scope resolution/facade type cron function like below

```
 \Cron::add('job-expired', '* * * * *', 

/**
 * @fn job-expired()
 * @brief Cron for job expired.
 *
 * Cron for job expired.
 * @returns Response
 */
function() 
{
    $jobs = Job::whereRaw("expiry_date < '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"))."'")->get();
    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
    //print_r($jobs);
    foreach($jobs as $job)
    {
        $job->status = 2;
        $job->save();
    //$job->expiry_date.' ' .$job->id.'<br>';
    }
});
```

Following comments are not working for this type of function.

```
/** @brief find certain url in array values
 *
 *  find certain url in array values
 *
 *  @param array values
 *  @param url specific url to search 
 *  @return Response
 */
```

I know class or function label comments and these are working fine except above type function comments.

Can anybody help me how to comment for this type of function?

Comment: Can anybody to check this?

Comment: The php code you provided is missing something. Is this the actual code or just an example? If it is the actual code, doxygen can get confused by the wrong parenthesis.

Comment: Please check this now.. this is laravel code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this:

I think Doxygen does not doucument your code, because it cannot find an expected keyword after the doc block.

So maybe it works if you write it this way:

```
\Cron::add('job-expired', '* * * * *', 
/**
 * Documentation here
 */
function() 
{
    ...
});
```

If this is also not working, you maybe have to use a filter to make the code look a little different to doxygen, so `function()` should become `function name()`.

You can get some examples for filters on my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AbcAeffchen/doxygen-php-filters).

Update:
I cam up with this regex that you can use as a filter

```
$regexp = '#(\/\*\*[\s\S]*?\*\/\s*)?(\\\\?Cron\s*::\s*add\()(\'|")([^,\']+)(\'|")(\s*,\s*[^,]+\s*,\s*)(\/\*\*[\s\S]*?\*\/\s*)?function\s*\(\s*\)#';
$replace = '$1$7public function $4()';
$source = preg_replace($regexp, $replace, $source);
```

It does two things:

1. It moves your doc comment to the right place
2. It gives the anonymous function a name and an access modifier

So both

```
/**
 * Docs
 */
\Cron::add('job-expired', '* * * * *', function()
{
    ...
});
```

and

```
\Cron::add('job-expired', '* * * * *',
/**
 * Docs
 */    
function()
{
    ...
});
```

become

```
/**
 * Docs
 */    
public function job-expired()
{
    ...
});
```

You can give it a try and I will add this to the git repository.

Comment: which function should I use from https://github.com/AbcAeffchen/doxygen-php-filters

Comment: @madankundu There is no function that fits you. You have to write your own one, if my first idea does not work. The link is only for examples on how a filter looks like.

Comment: @ AbcAeffchen your first idea is not working. I will check custom based if possible

Comment: @ AbcAeffchen this is working thanks by custom made. thanks

Comment: @madankundu would you like to share your solution? Maybe I can add this to the filter collection on GitHub

Comment: @ AbcAeffchen I have not ued regular expression. This will cause other other normal function. But I have static one  for one cron function.`$source = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
$source = str_replace("Cron::add('dailyemail-alerts', '* * * * *', function()","
        /**
        * @fn dailyemailalerts()
        * @brief Handle alerts etc.
        *
        * @returns Response
        */public function dailyemailalerts()", $source);
echo $source;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124513/discussion-between-madankundu-and-abcaeffchen).

Comment: @ AbcAeffchen I have added your regular expression code in filter page but this is not working. Please check my updated code as above as @fn job-expired()

Comment: @madankundu I think it is fixed now. Regex in PHP need to double escape the backslash, what I always forget.

Comment: @ AbcAeffchen sorry again this is not working at all. I have copied your new from above... but not

Comment: @ AbcAeffchen Have you tried this type of function. Please check in your system `Event::listen('auth.logout', function (){});`

Comment: @madankundu No the above code only works for `Cron` I only checked it in a php fiddle. It produces the result I expect and that you said is working. We should not talk here in the comments. You already moved this talk to a chat, so I will be there.